# Chain rule with partial derivative

Tags: partial-derivative

I have learned for the total derivative: 
$$\frac{dF(x(z),y(z))}{dz} = \frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dz} + \frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dz}.$$

Now I need the partial derivative:
$$ \frac{\partial F(\phi_1(x,z),\phi_2(y,z))}{\partial z}   .$$

Is it correct that:
$$ \frac{\partial F(\phi_1(x,z),\phi_2(y,z))}{\partial z}  =  
\frac{\partial F(\phi_1,\phi_2)}{\partial \phi_1} \frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial F(\phi_1,\phi_2)}{\partial \phi_2} \frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial z}  ?$$

I am confused because of the difference between total and partial derivative.

Comment: if $x$ and $y$ are independent from variable $z$ then your result is correct. Otherwise it is not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x$  and $y$  are independent from variable z  then your result is correct.

If $x=x(z)$ and $y=y(z)$, then it should be

$$
\frac{\partial F(\phi_1(x,z),\phi_2(y,z))}{\partial z} =
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \phi_1}
\left(
\frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} + 
\frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial z}
\right) +
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \phi_2}
\left(
\frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}+
\frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial z}
\right)
$$

Comment: You could explicitly state that if $x$ and $y$ are independent of $z$, their derivatives with respect to $z$ vanish. (OP's result)